# Is there way to manipulate entire row (or column) of data using SmartXLS

Tags: c#, smartxls

I have looked at their documentation and noticed that there are not many ways to manipulate entire rows or columns. They provide ways to manipulate range of data but not the whole.

I have been checking out http://www.smartxls.com/sample-list.htm but not really having any luck.

Would anybody know how? Knowing how many columns there are or rows there are would let me use those range methods but I do not think I see anything of that sort

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using Workbook.ExportDataTable then use Rows and Columns .Count to know the end.
If there are better ways, let me know.